# How to create correct post-request on C#?

Tags: c#, .net, http, post, httpclient

I have a site on localhost created to learn how to send http requests, I send a post request to it, trying to simulate sending data via forms, as a response I expect that the data I sent will be added to the database, as it happens when sending via forms, but this does not happen. I assume that I am sending the post request incorrectly and something is missing in it

The site: [localhost site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jGRd.png)

Post request: [Pose request headers and data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehDPX.png)

My C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AirParsingScript
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();
        static async Task Main()
        {
            var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "Person.DocId_pre", "421" },
                { "Person.DocId", "ADGAGSA" },
                { "Person.Email", "4124421" },
                { "Person.TeleNumber", "4444" }
            };

            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

            var response = await Client.PostAsync("https://localhost:44391", content);
            var responseString = await Client.GetStringAsync("https://localhost:44391");
            // var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(responseString);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging the site you are POSTing the data to, may be the problem is at that side.

Comment: Surely you have been inspecting value of response, if it returned 201 or what ever you expected?

Comment: @phuzi Yes, i am trying and its doesn't help me

Comment: @MikkoViitala I expect to see page code but don't see this

Comment: Does it work if you use something like Postman to send the POST request instead?

Comment: I think the problem could be the https. HttpClient doen't retrieve intermediate certificates, needed to get the connection sucessful. Please, try to do it without TLS security, connecting (if possible) to a plain http server. Does it work?

Comment: Why not just create a proper API endpoint in your application to receive this data, if you want to send requests to it progammatically, rather than trying to impersonate a GUI form? That's difficult, whereas calling an API endpoint is usually much easier, because they're designed for your exact scenario.

Comment: @Vic : HTTPS/TLS is working correctly since you are getting a response.  When TLS fails there is no response.

Comment: The error code 302 indicates the Server doesn't like the User Agent.  See following : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302?force_isolation=true

Comment: @ADyson I would like to understand and learn how to manually send post requests and only then go further. As a result, I plan to test this on a full-fledged site without API

Comment: @jdweng Hm. I get nothing in response. Now i think its TLS fails problem, thank you.

Comment: @jdweng Yes, i get code 302 but, however, data is still added to the database if I enter it manually

Comment: `I would like to understand and learn how to manually send post requests and only then go further. As a result, I plan to test this on a full-fledged site without API`...that really makes no sense. What you're trying to do now is more complicated and fiddly and error-prone than sending posts to a simple JSON-based API. You've got the whole concept backwards.

Comment: @Vic I don't  know how to do this and don't know is it possible but ill try to do it, thank you.

Comment: @ADyson Oh... okay, thank you, l'll take that into account.

Comment: @AntonyTona, in the server side you have to disable SSL to test if everything goes fine without https. If you're working with Visual Studio, you'll want to go to Project Properties => Debug tab. At the end of the page, uncheck the "Enable SSL" check. If you're using another dev IDE, let us know to help you

Comment: TLS is done before the request is sent.  If TLS fails the request is never sent.  If you are getting a response than TLS is working.